# Is Minecraft VR cross play with other platforms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, oculus-rift

I have recently started playing Minecraft VR on the Oculus rift. Can I play multiplayer with players on PC, Xbone and Switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minecraft VR can crossplay with all Bedrock Edition devices, as it is part of Windows 10 edition.

Answer (score 0):

From Oculus [site](https://www.oculus.com/blog/minecraft-is-now-available-on-rift-with-cross-platform-play/?locale=es_ES):

Plus, with this launch, you and your friends can explore Minecraft—simultaneously, cross platform—on Rift, Gear VR, iOS, Android, and Windows 10 devices.

Notice that Xbox and Switch are not listed to crossplay

Comment: PS4 neither. Guess the crossplay is between any platform that has setup to support VR in general, so VR headsets on PC and something like Google Cardboard for mobile.